# When to use store.dispatch() in my React / Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using mapDispatchToProps in my React / Redux app.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators( { fetchUsers }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

I have seen store.dispatch() being used inside containers, could I use that instead of mapDispatchToProps? I don't fully understand the **store.dispatch()** and where should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work if you render your app on server because you want to have different `store` instance per request on server. That's why `Redux` docs don't recommend this approach.

From the Docs of **[bindActionCreators](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html)**,

> You might ask: why don't we bind the action creators to the store
>   instance right away, like in classical Flux? The problem is that this
>   won't work well with universal apps that need to render on the server.
>   Most likely you want to have a separate store instance per request so
>   you can prepare them with different data, but binding action creators
>   during their definition means you're stuck with a single store
>   instance for all requests.

Also @Dan had a comment **[here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/916#issuecomment-149190441)** suggesting to use the `connect()` method himself.

Comment: Thanks! So basically I should always avoid using store.dispatch()? I saw it used in some repos, so thought it's something commonly used.

Comment: To get started with Redux, some tutorials intially started to make use of it. However as developments go on, better things come up :). And Dan had just come up with one such feature

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `connect` and `mapDispatchToProps`. Those give you access to dispatch and encapsulate the calls to dispatch in one place.

`store.dispatch` is useful if you have somewhere where `mapDispatchToProps` won't work, but I would avoid that as it's going to complicate your code needlessly.